# c++ dllimport: function call returns wrong result

Tags: c++

I'm trying to expose some methods in a c++ project, to call them from another one.

In my DLL project I have exposed the methods:

```
class IFilter
{
public:
  virtual double Filter(double n) = 0;
};

__declspec(dllexport) IFilter* ButterworthCreate(int order, double cutoffFrequency, double sampleRate)
{
  return new VButterworth(order, cutoffFrequency, sampleRate);
}

__declspec(dllexport) double ButterworthFilter(IFilter* handle, double n)
{
  double nResult = -1;
  if (handle){
    nResult = handle->Filter(n);
  }
  return nResult; 
}
```

In my Console app I'm trying to use them like this:

```
typedef long(*ButterworthCreate)(int, double, double);
typedef long(*ButterworthFilter)(int, double);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  std::string s = "D:\\WORK\\FilterConsole\\Debug\\Butterworth.dll";
  std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(s.begin(), s.end());
  LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();
  HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(sw);

  if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
    std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

 // resolve function address here
  ButterworthCreate create = (ButterworthCreate)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "ButterworthCreate");

  ButterworthFilter filter = (ButterworthFilter)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "ButterworthFilter");

  if (!create || !filter) {
    std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  int handle = create(1, 1, 1);
  double result = filter(handle, 10);

return 0;
}
```

The functions can be resolved and create returns a valid pointer, but the filter functions' result is negative.

The implementation of the filter functions is just

```
double CButterworth::Filter(double n)
{
  return n * n;
}
```

When debugging I can see the result is calculated correctly in the dll, but the result in my console app is strange.

Can anybody explain what I am missing? Thank you very much

Comment: `ButterworthCreate` types: `long` vs `IFilter*` vs `int`. I'm not that certain if they are all equal. You may have to fix your types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
__declspec(dllexport) double ButterworthFilter(IFilter* handle, double n)
```

and

```
typedef long(*ButterworthFilter)(int, double);
```

Those two are not equal. Especially on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits, while `int` are still 32 bits. Also note that `long` is *also* 32 bits when using MSVC, even on 64 bit systems.

If you want to create a C-compatible interface, I suggest you use [opaque data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) instead. And disable name-mangling using `extern "C"` as well.

Comment: I don't want to include the header in my console app, so I will go with `long`.

Comment: @user3292642 Even though I just told you that `long` is not correct? That it might not be able to hold a pointer, or even a `double` value? And that `long` to `double` conversion will not even work as you expect.

Comment: `long` is absolutely the *wrong* thing to use on windows for storing a pointer as windows follows LLP64. The only safe ways to pass a pointer around in an integer value is `std::intptr_t` or `LONG_PTR`

Comment: Well I think I will have to include the header file then and use IFilter*